# Ramifications of "Price" attribute type?

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, layered-navigation

I'm trying to understand the ramifications of setting an attribute type to "Price" when the attribute will not actually be a currency value.

The goal is to display length & width dimensional ranges (or a slider) in layered navigation. We've already purchased/installed Amasty Improved Layered Navigation. Currently my dimensional values are stored in an input type "text field" attribute with a validation of decimal number which unfortunately is not compatible.

The only option it appears is to change this attribute to input type "Price" but I want to make sure there are no unintended consequences.

It appears there may be some automatic UOM symbols created in the admin, but any additional insights or considerations would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does not seem like a clean solution for me, but they claim it "works just fine" ...  We should convince them to add a custom type, "numerical" without  currency symbols...